# Is it possible to limit forecasts made by bsts to positive values only?

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, bayesian

I am learning to use various forecasting packages available in R, and came across bsts(). The data I deal with is a time series of demands.

```
data=c(27, 2, 7, 7, 9, 4, 3, 3, 3, 9, 6, 2, 6, 2, 3, 8, 6, 1, 3, 8, 4, 5, 8, 5, 4, 4, 6, 1, 6, 5, 1, 3, 0, 2, 6, 7, 1, 2, 6, 2, 8, 6, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 3, 1, 6, 3, 4, 3, 7, 3, 4, 1, 7, 5, 6, 3, 4, 3, 9, 2, 1, 7, 2, 2, 9, 4, 5, 3, 4, 2, 4, 4, 8, 6, 3, 9, 2, 9, 4, 1, 3, 8, 1, 7, 7, 6, 0, 1, 4, 8, 9, 2, 5)
ts.main=ts(data, start=c(1910,1), frequency=12)
ss <- AddLocalLinearTrend(list(), y=ts.main)
ss <- AddSeasonal(ss, y=as.numeric(ts.temp), nseasons=12)
model <- bsts(as.numeric(ts.temp),
          state.specification = ss,
          niter = 1000)
pred <- predict(model, horizon = 12)
```

Is there way I can restrict `pred$mean` from becoming negative?

Comment: Is this a time series of counts?

Comment: Yes, it is a series of counts.

Answer (score 3):

Since your data are a time series of counts, you need to take that into account rather than assume Gaussian errors; for some discussion on this and elaboration of some approaches, see for example [Brandt et al 2000](http://www.utdallas.edu/~pbrandt/Patrick_Brandts_Website/Research_files/bwfp2000.pdf) and [Brandt and Williams 2001](http://www.utdallas.edu/~pbrandt/Patrick_Brandts_Website/Research_files/parpproofs.pdf). Luckily, the `bsts` package has a built-in functionality for this, the `family` option (see pages 24 to 26 of [the documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bsts/bsts.pdf)).

So, you can just do this

```
model <- bsts(as.numeric(ts.main),
              state.specification = ss,
              family = 'poisson',
              niter = 1000)
```

so that the `bsts()` function correctly considers the data as counts, which will solve your issue, since the draws from the posterior predictive distribution will then be non-negative by definition.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will go through the references you provided.